# what would the selectors be to get inputs inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery I want to get all the input controls for radio and checkbox inside of divs with specific classes.  Unless there is a div inside that div with another set class.

For example

```
 <div class="content-wrap">
<div><input id="chk1" type="checkbox"/></div>
<div class="normalCheck"><input id="chk2" type="checkbox" /></div>
</div>
```

In this example I want to perform some functions on 'chk1' but not on 'chk2'

I have tried this

```
 $('.content-wrap,.profile-acct-btn').not('.normalCheck').('input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]').each(function () {}
```

But this doesnt seem to get it - where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

instead of jQuery's `not()` function you can use the CSS [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) pseudo-class to filter out certain `<div>` elements based on their class:

```
$("div.content-wrap div:not(.normalCheck) input[type='checkbox']")
```

if for some reason you don't want to use that pseudo-class, you can still do the same thing in jQuery with `$.find()`:

```
$("div.content-wrap > div").not("div.normalCheck").find("input[type='checkbox']")
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/90bmbvsg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In CSS: The selector for input fields of type **radio** and **checkbox** looks like this

```
.content-wrap > div > input[type="radio"], .content-wrap > div:not(.normalCheck) > input[type="checkbox"]
```

In jQuery, you should use the above selector like so:

```
var radioCheckboxInput = $('.content-wrap > div > input[type="radio"], .content-wrap > div:not(.normalCheck) > input[type="checkbox"]');
```

Implementing this selector is as simple as using the variable `radioCheckboxInput` as shown below:

```
radioCheckboxInput.each(function(){
    //... Do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is js code that works as you need

```
$('.content-wrap,.profile-acct-btn').find('input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]').not('.normalCheck input').each(function () { alert($(this).attr('id')); });
```